# Limit points of finite sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am confused about whether (a) a finite and (b) a countable set has limit points. It obviously depends on the nature of the underlying space (which dictates what a "neighbourhood" is), right?

But let's start the other way around. Consider an uncountable metric space $X$ with a metric $d$, and a set $E\subset X$. If $p$ is a limit point of $E$, then every neighbourhood of $p$ contains infinitely many points of $E$.

This can be easily seen. Let $N_r(p)$ be an $r$-neighbourhood of $p$ (ie. an open ball of radius $r$ centred at $p$). Let us assume that $N_r(p)\cap E=\{q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_n\}$, ie. it is finite. We can pick an $s=min_{1\le i\le n}d(p,q_i)$ (ie. the $q_i$ from $N_r(p)\cap E$ that is closest to $p$. According to our assumption, $N_s(p)$ contains no point of $E$, which contradicts our assumption that $p$ is a limit point of $E$.

Having established this, we could twist it and say that a finite set $E\subset X$ cannot have limit points. For if it lives inside an uncountable metric space $X$, we can always find a small (whatever small means) neighbourhood of $p\in E$ not containing other elements of $E$.

(1) I suppose we could state the same about countably infinite sets? (that they have no limit points in such an uncountable metric space $X$?)

(2) What if $X$ is countable? Say $X=\mathbb{N}$ (natural numbers) and $E=\{0, 1,2\}$. Are $0$, $1$, and $2$ limit points of $E$? Also, what happens at $0$ (neighbourhood should contain a ball, but we can't go beyond $0$?

(3) What if $X=\mathbb{Z}$? (integers)

Answer (score 0):

Set having limit points does not in general depend on whether it is countable or not: Since $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R}$, every irrational number is a limit point of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. For a space where no subset has limit points you can take $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric.

Numbers 2 and 3 of your question are discrete metric spaces with a countable underlying set.

Comment: Thanks. What is the discrete metric?

Comment: And what about (a) $E=\{1,2,3\}$, (b) $E=\mathbb{N}$, and (c) $E=\mathbb{Z}$, all in $R$ with the standard metric.